# Does Lock object in python 2 have time out?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm learning multithread in python. I write some code to practice it

```
import threading
import time

Total = 0
class myThead(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, num):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.num = num
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
    def run(self):
        global Total
        self.lock.acquire()
        print "%s acquired" % threading.currentThread().getName()
        for i in range(self.num):
            Total += 1
        print Total
        print "%s released" % threading.currentThread().getName()
        self.lock.release()

t1 = myThead(100)
t2 = myThead(100)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

if i pass 100 to thread t1 and t2, they go correctly.

```
Thread-1 acquired
100
Thread-1 released
Thread-2 acquired
200
Thread-2 released
```

But when i try with bigger numbler. For example, i pass 10000. It prints out unexpected output.

```
Thread-1 acquired
Thread-2 acquired
14854
Thread-1 released
15009
Thread-2 released
```

I try many times but no thing changes. So i think Lock object in python have timeout. If Lock acquire for long time, it will allow other thread can go. Can anyone explain me about it. Thank you!

Comment: You've made two independent locks. You want one lock for both threads to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each thread gets its own lock, so acquiring t1's lock doesn't stop t2 from acquiring its own lock.

Perhaps you could make `lock` a class attribute, so all instances of `myThread` share one.

```
class myThead(threading.Thread):
    lock = threading.Lock()

    def __init__(self, num):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.num = num
```

Result:

```
Thread-1 acquired
10000
Thread-1 released
Thread-2 acquired
20000
Thread-2 released
```

Answer (score 3):

No, locks do not have a timeout. What is happening is that they are not actually sharing the same lock, as a new one is created every time you instantiate the object in the **init** method. If all instances of that class will always share the same lock, then you could throw it in as a class property. However, explicit is better than implicit. I would personally put the lock as an argument in the init method. Something like this.

```
import threading
import time

Total = 0
class myThead(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, num, lock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.num = num
        self.lock = lock


    def run(self):
        global Total
        self.lock.acquire()
        print "%s acquired" % threading.currentThread().getName()
        for i in range(self.num):
            Total += 1
        print Total
        print "%s released" % threading.currentThread().getName()
        self.lock.release()

threadLock = threading.Lock()
t1 = myThead(100, threadLock)
t2 = myThead(100, threadLock)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

That way both instances of the class share the same lock.

Comment: I think in my case use, using class attribute is best way. But your answer is another good approach to get it work correctly. Thanks for your help!